# "Request access" to the app store connect API button is gray / disabled

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm the admin/account holder of my individual Apple developer account. When I go to the app store connect api the button for requesting access is grayed out/disabled. Haven't used it before, but the account itself has had apps in the appstore and is more than seven years old.

If I add another user to the account and give it admin access, and go to the app store connect api page, it flickers an error-page and goes back (not the browser, but the actual web page doing this).

Here's an image of the disabled button.
[image: Grayed out button]

Comment: Seems to be a common issue at the moment, as also reported in the Apple Developer Forums: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/110531

Comment: I can't believe I missed those comments that are literally just a few days old. I've been scouring the forums. I need to improve my googling skills it seems. Thank you for taking the time to search it out for me!

Comment: No worries. I am automatizing the whole screenshot stuff at the moment and the last missing step is auto uploading to the App Store, so I have the same issue as you have 

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I tried but the solution doesn't work.
I found other solution (it works with Admin account, no need to be account holder):

1. Right-click on “Request Access” button and select “Inspect” from the context menu;
2. Replace `class="sc-gZMcBi tb-btn--disabled giNnHm"` with `class="sc-gZMcBi"`
3. After applying the changes, the button will work

Comment: This is from an answer on the forum. It seems to work, but I'm not exactly sure if it's "ok" with Apple. So I'd not recommend doing it, but yes it does seem to work. Which is fantastically weird in some way.

Comment: I only find this answer on the forum but it doesn't work for me so I tried to modify it: 

 Right-click on "Request Access" button and select "Inspect" from the context menu;

 Remove type = "primary" from the list of button attributes and remove the word "disabled" from the button class name;

 After applying the changes, the button will work

Comment: It is actually working now again without the HTML/CSS hack, but nice solution 

Comment: @LudiwineFafournoux saved my day! Thanks :) a problem like this is so untypical for Apple... ;)

Comment: Saved my day. Works like a charm. Not sure why they have made it like this that the admin can't request access for this.

Comment: I don't understand why apple doesn't fix the issue  but many thanks for your solution!